# How to make objects countable to get if-statements working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, if-statement

Data doesn't get inserted into the database because it doesn't pass the if-statements. I am currently making a form to insert polls and corresponding answers into the database. Apparently the variables in the if-statements are non-countable objects (e.g. `$answers`, `$rows`. How do I make these countable, do I have to make them arrays? Or do I have to completely change the if-statements? These statements are going wrong:
`if (count($answers) <= 1)`
`if (count($rows) == 0)`
`foreach($answers as $answer)`

Here is my code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    // get form data and escape it properly
    $poll = strip_tags($_POST["poll"]);
    $rawAnswers = strip_tags($_POST["answers"]);

    //
    $formattedAnswers = str_replace(", ", ",", $rawAnswers);
    $answers = explode(",", $formattedAnswers);

    // add answers to database
    include("opendb.php");

    if (count($answers) <= 1) {
        echo "<p>It makes no sense to add less than or equal to one answer.</p>";
    } else {
        // add poll to database if it is not already there
        $pollNewCheck = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM polls WHERE poll = ?');
        $pollNewCheck->bindValue(1, $poll, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pollNewCheck->execute();
        $rows = $pollNewCheck->fetch();
        if (count($rows) == 0) {
            $pollQuery = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO polls (poll) VALUES ( ? )');
            $pollQuery->bindValue(1, $poll, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $pollQuery->execute();
            echo "<h2>Poll added!</h2><p id=\"addedPoll\">$poll</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<h2>Existing poll!</h2><p id=\"addedPoll\">\"$poll\" is already in the database. The answers you entered have been added to it.</p>";
        }

        // get poll_id for added poll
        $pollIDQuery = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM polls WHERE poll = ?');
        $pollIDQuery->bindValue(1, $poll, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $pollIDQuery->execute();
        $row = $pollIDQuery->fetch();
        $pollID = $row[0];

        echo "<h3>These are the available answers you added:</h3>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach($answers as $answer) {
            $answerQuery = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO answers (answer, poll_id) VALUES ( ?, ? )');
            $answerQuery->bindValue(1, $answer, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $answerQuery->bindValue(2, $pollID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $answerQuery->execute();
            echo "<li>$answer</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        echo "<p id=\"returnToPanel\"><a href=\"/admin.php\">Return to admin panel</a></p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `strip_tags` arbitrarily like that. If you're concerned about HTML escaping issues then use `htmlentities` if and when you display that content in HTML.

Comment: If you actually get an array from the explode then it works: https://3v4l.org/3ivXm do a `print_r($answers);` to see.

Comment: @AbraCadaver this is what `print_r($answers);` gives back:

`Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test2 [2] => test3 [3] => test4 ) `

Comment: Please edit the question and add information. Don't put debug info in a comment.

Comment: So `echo count($answers);` should be `4` and so the `if` is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will add more to this answer when you provide more information.

This will go a long way to solving your issues:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Assuming $_POST["answers"] contains "aaaa, bbbbb, cccc", then the explode will work. There's no way to know for sure because you have not provided sample input.

```
$rawAnswers = strip_tags($_POST["answers"]);  // Don't know what is in here
$formattedAnswers = str_replace(", ", ",", $rawAnswers);
$answers = explode(",", $formattedAnswers);
```

PDOStatement::fetch returns null or false if no data is found. Therefore, do this:

```
    $row = $pollNewCheck->fetch();
    if ( empty($row) ) {
        // poll was not found in the database
    } else {
        // poll was found in the database
    }
```

Move the `prepare` out of the loop.

```
    $answerQuery = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO answers (answer, poll_id) VALUES ( ?, ? )');
    foreach($answers as $answer) {
        $answerQuery->bindValue(1, $answer, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $answerQuery->bindValue(2, $pollID, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $answerQuery->execute();
        echo "<li>$answer</li>";
    }
```

Comment: This is what I get when my input is `test1,test2,test3,test4` and i use `print_r`: `Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test2 [2] => test3 [3] => test4 )`

Comment: The stuff in the comment before this one is when i actually put the statement after the answer formatting. This is what I directly get: 
`Array ( [poll] => Test [answers] => test1,test2,test3,test4 ) `